# How run powershell scripts in docker compose

Tags: powershell, docker, containers, docker-for-windows

I am trying to spin a new container and run a powershell script with in the new container. This is my docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    image: "iis"
    command: powershell -executionpolicy bypass "C:\docker\sharedFiles\scripts\generic_script.ps1" #tried with containerpath "C:\sharedFiles\scripts\generic_script.ps1"
    ports:
    - "80:8000"    
    networks:
      nat:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.2
    volumes:
    - "C:/docker/sharedFiles:c:/sharedFiles"
networks:
  nat:
    external: true
```

I am able to spin the cotnainer, but the PS script is not getting executed. What am i missing ?

Comment: What is your base image? You need to overrider `entrypoint` if you want to run a different command on start up. In general what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I want to spin a IIS container and run some custom PS commands on the container that are required by my application. I am using IIS container from docker hub as my base image.

Comment: Do you need to run this command each time container starts or it can be part of the image?

Comment: I need the command to be run every time container starts..

Comment: The best way to do that is to modify your docker file to override entrypoint of IIS like below `powershell c:\yourscript.ps1; .\servicemonitor.exe w3svc`

Comment: Thank you, i will try that. So in nutshell we cannot configure to run scripts in compose ? What will be the use case to write shell script in compose ?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian Entrypoints cannot be overridden, that's why they recommend the command / CMD reference.

Comment: Yes, they can be. I do it in my images. CMD is being executed after Entrypoint returns but Entrypoint never returns back command prompt in IIS image.

Comment: Here is specifically what I use for IIS image https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2017/07/20/replacing-servicemonitor-exe-with-iis-error-log-events-in-windows-iis-container/

Comment: @user1550159 If you override in your docker file Entrypoint of IIS image with c:\yourscript; .\serviemonitor.exe w3svc then there is no need to add shell execute in your compose file. What is the business case would you have to have base image entrypoint different for custom image

Comment: Hello @user1550159 any update on this one? I am facing exactly the same issue